# C# How to get two parameters from a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do something easy, but wondering about the best way..

Most of my API get services accept parameters, and I've used the URL to get them. Up until now I've used :

```
[HttpGet("ACTION/{paramName}")]
public IActionResult ACTION(string param1)
```

This works fine, and I'm not looking to replace it. My question is, what do I do when I need two parameters? I found a way to do it by :

```
[HttpGet("ACTION/{param1}/{param2}")]
public IActionResult ACTION(string param1,string param2)
```

But it seems ugly and I'm sure there is a better way to capture the parameters.

Comment: Why does it looks ugly?

Comment: Isn't it ? In the future many people might use this feature . I want to create the best way for them to communicate with the service @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: That looks good to me

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

First, as you said ugly:

```
[HttpGet("ACTION/{param1}/{param2}")]
public IActionResult ACTION(string param1,string param2)
```

The URL in this case: `/ACTION/somevalue1/somevalue2`

And second, maybe ugly too:

```
[HttpGet("ACTION")]
public IActionResult ACTION(string param1,string param2)
```

The URL in that case: `/ACTION?param1=somevalue1&param2=somevalue2`

Answer (score 0):

You might have a parameter which is available for the entire class and might be defined like this one:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
   [HttpPut("Buy")]      // Matches PUT 'api/Products/Buy'
   [HttpPost("Checkout")] // Matches POST 'api/Products/Checkout'
   public IActionResult Buy()
}
```

I really prefer using the examples from the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing), since they're pretty much okay.